# Correct way to deploy publish asp.net core application. Console / IIS / WinService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've realized an ASP.NET Core application that currently runs as Console Application. I've been asked to deploy for a customer under IIS and for a next customer as Windows Service. In the past for .NET Full Framework application, I used [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to run it as a console/windows service.

Have I change my code, or it's just a matter of publishing profile? I've seen that for IIS the publish generates a .exe file, should it exist or should it be a DLL file only?

Thanks

Comment: in asp.net core we have a console app that serves as host and runs as server called kerstel

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ?